# react await on component property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I have a component that used to call sync function `executeCode`.
The problem it's my `executeCode` is async function, this functions return `true` or `false`, but now my function is async, i need to use await to get the value, because an async functions give a promise. The problem is i can't use await, i've tried an anonymous function or promise with `.then()` but it's not applicable in this case, because i need instantly the value. `executeCode` is now async because it's needed for another operations.

```
executeCode = async ( methodCode ='', params = {} ) => {
  const result = await crudCode[methodCode](params);
  return result.valueToReturn;
};

render() {
  return (
    <Field
      name="datedeferred"
      component={FormField}
      executeCode={this.executeCode}
      typeInput="text"
      disabled={ 
        this.executeCode( 'onDisabled', { inputFullNameWithLine: 'datedeferred',formProps: this.props })
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could run your `async` function in `componentDidMount` and put the result in `state` instead and use that.

**Example**

```
function someAsyncCheck() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 1000));
}

class App extends Component {
  state = { loading: true, disabled: false };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const result = await someAsyncCheck();
    this.setState({ loading: false, disabled: result });
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, disabled } = this.state;

    if (loading) {
      return null;
    }

    return <input disabled={disabled} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but i can't change the logic, it's complex, there are onchange with debounce that modify state continually, my question is not about change the logic but manage async and await inside a property

Comment: @DDave You can't have asynchronous logic in `render`, that's why I changed the logic. It is simply impossible to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you used in your pseudocode, ever time a re-render is triggered, the async function would be called but the render is depedent on the result - and so one hits a dead end. A solution is to watch the variable in question for changes and then trigger the async on change. Take the result of the async and set a state managed variable. React will pick up the managed variable changing and trigger a re-render. See below.

```
const [buttonDisabled, setButtonDisabled] = useState<boolean>(false)

useEffect(() => {
  someAsnycCheck().then(result => setButtonDisabled(result));
},[params])

return (
  <button disabled={buttonDisabled}...>
)
```

This basically means: watch `params` for changes, then call the async function. When the result arrives, set `buttonDisabled` to the result.